# query doesn't return way based on related nodes

Tags: overpass-api, relationship-class

Way 445962072 has 5 related nodes. If I query on two of more of these nodes, the way isn't returned. The query I used is

```
node(id:8093775,8093776)->.allnodes;
way(bn.allnodes)->.ways;
foreach .ways -> .singleway (
  node.allnodes(w.singleway);
  way.singleway(bn)(if:count(nodes) == allnodes.count(nodes));
  out geom;
);
```

I checked the relationship in JOSM but I see nothing wrong.

Is there some kind of error in the overpass API or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue, way 445962072 is getting returned here in the query result. On which instance are you testing?

Comment: I'm using https://overpass-turbo.eu/

Comment: overpass-turbo.eu is using version 0.7.54.12, which is one of the latest I think. I have an older overpass-API running locally in a docker container (v0.6.91) which is not returning any result either.

Comment: overpass turbo is just a web frontend, so that doesn't tell which server you're using. What do you see underneath "Settings" -> "General"? There's no official Docker container available for Overpass API, so I cannot really help you with that. Please get in touch with the person who provided that container to you, if that's you own container, upgrade to 0.7.54

Comment: Sorry, I think I made an error in commenting out another query above this one. If I include the query as is, it works in the web front-end. Not sure why it works in may 'home grown' docker container. Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query depends on language elements, which have been introduced only in a more recent version 0.7.54, more specifically that's the additional filter `(if:count(nodes) == allnodes.count(nodes))`.

Your home grown docker container is running a much older version, which simply discards those those elements without returning an error message, though. This way, your query returns invalid data on your own local instance, but correct results on the public server.

Recommendation would be to set up a new container using the latest version from https://dev.overpass-api.de/releases